# How to increase the amount of time Android speech recoognition listens for?

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I have tried putting the following intent data:

```
Long googleVoiceTimeout = new Long(15000);

speechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
speechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_MINIMUM_LENGTH_MILLIS, googleVoiceTimeout);
speechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS, googleVoiceTimeout);
speechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_POSSIBLY_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS,googleVoiceTimeout);
speechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PARTIAL_RESULTS,true);
```

But even after doing all that it still sometime stops listening after one second of silence. There is no consistency.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, these values may have no effect. It depends on the implementation of the speech recognizer which may vary on the different versions of Android and/or different phone models.

For example here is the doc of `EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_POSSIBLY_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS` :

```
/**
 * The amount of time that it should take after we stop hearing speech to consider the input
 * possibly complete. This is used to prevent the endpointer cutting off during very short
 * mid-speech pauses. 
 * 
 * Note that it is extremely rare you'd want to specify this value in an intent. If
 * you don't have a very good reason to change these, you should leave them as they are. Note
 * also that certain values may cause undesired or unexpected results - use judiciously!
 * Additionally, depending on the recognizer implementation, these values may have no effect.
 */
public static final String EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_POSSIBLY_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS =
        "android.speech.extras.SPEECH_INPUT_POSSIBLY_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS";
```

You can find all of the `Intent` properties described [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.java).